# How to setup Postfix using ubuntu server to work with " Google Apps for Work" - email

Tags: server, email, postfix, google, gmail

I am trying to get my email to relay through gmail as admin@"mydomain.com".

I need this cause my emails do not even make it through to spam.I am using postFix. Google would like me to delete my MX records and setup new ones. Where do I do this? I have tried to Google this and just cant find the answer I need.

I need to setup new MX records and delete old one if there are any. I have already set my meta tag on my home page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So my answer is that nothing on the server needs to be changed. The MX records still reside on your DNS (not sure in which case it would not), so you change the MX with your DNS even although you do not have a cpanel like setup and you have postfix.

Hope that helps others in the future :)